# Target Downgrade

Tags: android, google-play

I have released an app on the app store with the target api being 23. A user has contacted me informing me that my app immediately crashes on devices running 23. After researching, a library my app is relying on crashes if the target is 23. I set the target to 22 which fixes the error, however, now google play will not let me update the app because **"It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously used M permissions (target SDK 23 and above) to APKs which use old style permissions (target SDK 22 and below)."**

This is a paid app so I can't just remove it from the store and republish under a new name. Anyone run into this before? Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, once you set your `targetSdkVersion` to 23, you are using [Android 6.0's runtime permissions](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-runtime-permissions) and cannot downgrade to target an older `targetSdkVersion`.

As mentioned in the [Picking your compile, min, and targetSdkVerison blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd):

> That doesn’t mean you have to use every new feature introduced nor should you blindly update your targetSdkVersion without testing  — **please, *please* test before updating your targetSdkVersion!** Your users will thank you.

You'll have to update your app's compatibility with API 23, removing libraries that specifically prohibit targeting API 23 and ensuring that you [request dangerous permissions at runtime](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: That's a really bad rationale since this also applies to the alpha channel, and it makes it unnecessarily difficult, if not impossible, to use continuous delivery of new features *TO ALPHA USERS*.  This is just terrible.

Comment: @user239558 - you most definitely can continue to do that. Just make sure your alpha version codes remain higher than your production version codes. I'd strongly suggest prefixing your version codes with something release dependent rather than always auto-incrementing. That's been a recommendation in the docs since day 1

Comment: this is the target sdk version, not the version code.

Comment: @user239558 - perhaps then I don't understand your comment. You can most definitely have an alpha channel that targets API 23+ and a production channel that does not and deliver updates to both channels simultaneously. You just have to make sure alpha users continue to get alpha builds and you do that by controlling your version codes properly.

Comment: as soon as one alpha user gets target version 25, then no other alpha with target version 22 can be uploaded.  So it is not possible, in general, to have an alpha channel used as an CD artifact without a lot of cushioning and engineering around the delicate google play.  I must, in the CD pipeline, refuse any developer who tries to upload target version 23+ or the option of pushing target version 22 is lost for that channel.

Answer (score 0):

instead of downgrade you can add conditions for relate the parts of your code to the supported versions.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
       //put whole code here if nothing supported for 23+
    }
```